# Inserting a row in multiple tables, and maintaining a relationship separately

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am a bit lost trying to insert my data in a specific scenario from an excel sheet into 4 tables, using SSIS.

Each row of my excel sheet needs to be split into 3 tables. The identity column value then needs to be inserted into a 4th mapping table to hold the relationship. How do I achieve this efficiently using SSIS 2008?

Note in the below example, its fixed that both col4 and 5 go into 3rd table.

Here is data example

**Excel**

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
a     b     c     d     3
a     x     c     y     5
```

**Table1**

```
PK  col
1   a
2   a
```

**Table2**

```
PK    col1  col2
1     b     c
2     x     c
```

**Table3**

```
PK  Col
1   d
2   3
3   y
4   5
```

**Map_table**

```
PK   Table1_ID  Table2_ID  Table3_ID
1    1          1          1
2    1          1          2
2    2          2          3
2    2          2          4
```

I am fine even if just a SQL based approach is suggested, as I do not ave any mandate to use SSIS only. Additional challenge is that in table 2, if a same data row exists, I want to use that ID in the map table, instead of inserting duplicate rows!

Comment: Do you really need an SSIS based solution? Looking at this, I get the feeling that it could be solved easier with a SQL script after importing the source Excel into your database.

Comment: @Josien Everything can be achieved with SQL Scripts, but SSIS is a good way to have an overview of your data flows... He's asking for something that can be solved with SQL, but maybe this package is part of a bigger picture.

Comment: No, SSIS is not a mandatory as a requirement. I just need a repeatable way to import the excel data into these tables. I thought perhaps SSIS would help better in this need.

Comment: I think Josien has the right idea here.  SSIS can be very useful, but I recommend you import the Excel file as-is and then use a sproc to peel out the components and insert them where needed.  You could put these two steps in SSIS, if it's meant to be part of a larger process.

Answer (score 3):

Multicast is the component you are looking for. This component takes an input source and DUPLICATE it as many output. You can, in that scenario, have an Excel source and duplicate the flow to insert the data into your Table1, Table2 and Table3.

Now, the tricky part is getting back those identities into your Map_Table. Either you dont use IDENTITY and use some other means (like a GUID, or an incremental counter of your own that you would setup as a derived column before the multicast) or you use the `@@IDENTITY` to retrive the last inserted identity. Using `@@IDENTITY` sounds like a pain to me for your current scenario, but that's up to you. If the data is not that huge, I would go for a GUID.

`@@IDENTITY` don't work well with BULK operations. It will retrieve only the last identity created. Also, keep in mind that I talked about @@IDENTITY, but you may want to use `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')` instead to retrieve the last identity for a specific table. `@@IDENTITY` retrieve the last identity created within your session, whatever the scope. You can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to retrive the last identity within your scope.

Comment: I'm happy to be proven wrong, but using the standard OLE Destination in SSIS does not allow you to get the @@identity values (nor can you use OLE with a SQL script destination in an attempt to use the OUTPUT clause). Pity though, it'd be handy.

Comment: You can use OLEDB Command and a stored procedure to insert and return the @@identity -- just a bit more work ;-)

Comment: Yes, an OLEDB command would work but that's not the OLE Destination. Also, the OLEDB command offers *horrible* performance as it will issue a statement **per** row.

Comment: You cannot use @@IDENTITY with bulk operations. That's why I suggested the OP to generate the ID himself, I should habve specified it in my answer.